# Find bugs reports across multiple code bases

Tags: java, findbugs

There is a product which runs multiple reports to indicate the quality of different code bases  which you may have. Find bugs is one of the reports.

It's quite visual and is web based.

I just can't remember what it's called! Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sonar : http://www.sonarsource.org/ ?